# JAX-RS hostname change possible?

Tags: api, rest, jax-rs

I'm currently developing a REST web service using JAX-RS.

Can I change the host name which is currently "local host 8080"?
Also, can I use https?

I want the name to represent an API host like twitter ""https://api.twitter.com" or is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

JAX-RS uses only a subset of the URI path for matching requests (the part relative to your application context). Changes to the domain and schema (http/https) should not make a difference.

Comment: I'm demonstrating an API for a web service, so api in the domain would be beneficial visually.